# InstallShield 2020 - installscript to MSI - migrating first installs, major upgrades, minor updates, patches

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, migrate, installscript

First of all let me point out that our MSI basic install(s) are not that basic...

Currently we have three separate installscript projects that are not connected via the product code, and replace the product registration when they are applied.
What we would like to do is follow the MSI standard and give to our product a single GUID as product code, and generate different upgrade code based on the type of install:

- **first install** -  deploy:

  - a) some basic components that can be removed during the uninstall of the product,
  - b) some complex components that can not be uninstalled during the uninstall of the product, and
  - c) some other complex components (i.e. database server,) which may or may not be uninstalled during the uninstall of the product (up to the customer at uninstall time.)
- **Major upgrade** - Identifies product is installed correctly, simple and complex components, and is of a minimum version, applies major database upgrades, and updates some features/components.
- **Minor upgrade and update** (patches) - Identifies product is installed correctly, simple and complex components, and is of a specific version, applies minor database upgrades, and does not update features/components.

How do I make my MSI major and minor upgrades identify that the product is already installed but installed by the original installscript package. And without uninstalling the product's files, link the existing folder and files to the new Features/components -  essentially 'take-over' the product - so, if the uninstall is run it will behave like if it was installed with the MSI packages from the first time?

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that the MSI project(s) have the same GUID as the original InstallScript project? That may still not cause IS to think the product is already installed since they're two different install types (installscript vs MSI).

Comment: Steve, thank you for your enquire, It made me re-read my question, and I realized I have not presented the question correctly.

Comment: Your comment also made realized that our first upgrade will be the only one that will have to have that additional 'logic' to replace the installcript product registration via the install type (MSI product not found,) and register the new MSI product. What I am still puzzling about is how, that first Mayor Upgrade, I will be able to register the features/components with our new MSI product, and if and how I can associate existing files with them.